# convert a 2D numpy array with positive and negative values, into an RGB images

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQNYa.png)I'have a  2D numpy array (128 x 128) with values positive and negatives. I want to convert it into an RGB image.
My idea is that each pixel in the image has a colour according to the value (e.g. negative values have a colour towards blue and red for positive values). I thought this would be automatic when I converted into an RGB image but it kept on being grey. The images in the link is an example, it is in greyscale,but i want to add colors

```
image = (image - image.min()) / (image.max() - image.min()) #to normalize
image = (image * 255).astype(np.uint8)
image = Image.fromarray(image, 'L').convert('RGB')
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Each pixel value is duplicated when converting from a gray image to an RGB image. So it still looks like a grayscale image.

I will briefly show you an example.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = np.random.rand(28, 28)
image = (image - image.min()) / (image.max() - image.min()) #to normalize
image = (image * 255).astype(np.uint8)

print(image[0][0]) #100

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

image[0][0] #[100, 100, 100]
```

The first pixel value of normalized gray scale image is 100.
The first value after conversion to RGB is [100, 100, 100].

Add example using HSV

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = np.random.rand(28, 28)
image = (image - image.min()) / (image.max() - image.min()) #to normalize
image = image * 120 #you can modify range of H for HSV
image = np.expand_dims(image, 2)

sv = np.zeros([28, 28, 2])
sv[:, :, 0] = 200 #you can modify value of S for HSV
sv[:, :, 1] = 100 #you can modify value of V for HSV

hsv_image = np.concatenate([image, sv], 2).astype(np.uint8)
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```

Then you can get RGB image which has color from red to blue.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, so I shouldn't convert to grayscale first?

Comment: I think it would be better to normalize between the blue and red values using HSV color space instead of the min to max values of the image. Then convert it to RGB color space.

Comment: can you add an example?

Comment: @kascodegama1 I added the example. you can modify the values referring to the HSV color space.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#"image" holds your 2D image data. np.shape(image) = 128 x 128

plt.imshow(image, interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('image.pdf')
```

Comment: This should be extended, not I really like using matplotlib, it allows for "linearization" of the colours, and you can pick and make your own colour scheme

Comment: Please include some text descriptions in your answers (not just the code)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.